# Working with load and on function

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
<div id="gll_select">
            <script>
             var caffe = $("#caffe").val();
             $("#gll_select").load("<?php echo base_url() ?>form/galleries", {id : caffe});  
            </script>
</div>
```

which loads this:

```
<select name="gll" id="gll">
    <?php foreach ($galleries as $key) : ?>
        <?php if($id == $key['caffe_id']) :?>
        <option value="<?php echo $key['id_gallery'] . " " . $key['name'] ?>"><?php echo $key['name'] ?></option>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>        
</select>
```

and this one:

```
$("#gll").on('change',function(){
    var cff_name = $("#caffe_name").val();
    var gll = $("#gll").val();
    var gll = gll.split(' ');
    var gll_id = gll[0];            
    var data = "cff_name=" + cff_name + "&gll_id=" + gll_id;
    $('table tbody').empty();
    $.ajax({                
                url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>upload/get_files',
                dataType: 'json', 
                data : data,
                success : function(data) {                   
                    var fu = $('#fileupload').data('fileupload'), 
                    template;
                    fu._adjustMaxNumberOfFiles(-data.length);
                    template = fu._renderDownload(data)
                    .appendTo($('#fileupload .files'));                    
                    // Force reflow:
                    fu._reflow = fu._transition && template.length &&
                    template[0].offsetWidth;
                    template.addClass('in');
                    $('#loading').remove();
                }
});
});
```

Problem is that on change nothing happens. What I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should attach the handler for `#gll` element after the `load()` call has completed (which actually acts like an asynchronous ajax call): probably at the moment you have defined the handler for the `change` event before you load the html code, so nothing happen because the select doesn't exist yet.

try to change in this way

```
$("#gll_select").load("<?php echo base_url() ?>form/galleries", {id : caffe}, 
    function() {
        $("#gll").on('change',function(){
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: load function is at the begging of the page, and onchange is at the bottom (there is a lot of HTML code in between).

Comment: load() performs an asynchronous ajax call. it doesn't really matter where that code is placed. try to put a `console.log($('#gll').length)` just before you attach the handler: does it return `1`?

Comment: I am getting 0. What does it mean?

Comment: it means exactly what I said: when you attached the event handler, the element still **not** exist because `load()` get the html asynchronously. Some (milli|tenth of) seconds can pass before you get the answer from server. So you have to attach the handler inside a callback, after `load()` has completed